# How to filter given width of lines in a image?

Tags: c++, opencv, math, image-processing, detection

I need to filter given width of lines in a image.

I am coding a program which will detect lines of road image. And I found something like that but can't understand logic of it. My function has to do that:
I will send *image* and *width of line* in terms of pixel size(e.g 30 pixel width), the function will filter just these lines in image.

I found that code:

```
void filterWidth(Mat image, int tau) // tau=width of line I want to filter
int aux = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < quad.rows; ++j)
{
    unsigned char *ptRowSrc = quad.ptr<uchar>(j);
    unsigned char *ptRowDst = quadDst.ptr<uchar>(j);

    for (int i = tau; i < quad.cols - tau; ++i)
    {
        if (ptRowSrc[i] != 0)
        {
            aux = 2 * ptRowSrc[i];
            aux += -ptRowSrc[i - tau];
            aux += -ptRowSrc[i + tau];
            aux += -abs((int)(ptRowSrc[i - tau] - ptRowSrc[i + tau]));

            aux = (aux < 0) ? (0) : (aux);
            aux = (aux > 255) ? (255) : (aux);

            ptRowDst[i] = (unsigned char)aux;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the mathematical explanation of that code? And how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Read up about convolution filters.  This code is a particular case of a *1 dimensional* convolution filter (it only convolves with other pixels on the currently processed line).

The value of aux is started with 2 * the current pixel value, then pixels on either side of it at distance tau are being subtracted from that value.  Next the absolute *difference* of those two pixels is also subtracted from it. Finally it is capped to the range 0...255 before being stored in the output image.

If you have an image:

0011100

This convolution will cause the centre 1 to gain the value:

```
2 * 1
- 0
- 0
- abs(0 - 0)
= 2
```

The first '1' will become:

```
2 * 1
- 0
- 1
- abs(0 - 1)
= 0
```

And so will the third '1' (it's a mirror image).

And of course the 0 values will always stay zero or become negative, which will be capped back to 0.

Comment: note: tau is the *half-width* of the line being filtered... tau is both added and subtracted from the current position

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather weird filter. It takes the pixel values three by three on the same line, with a tau spacing. Let these values by Vl, V and Vr.

The filter computes - Vl + 2 V - Vr, which can be seen as a second derivative, and deducts |Vl - Vr|, which can be seen as a first derivative (also called gradient). The second derivative gives a maximum response in case of a maximum configuration (Vl < V > Vr); the first derivative gives a minimum response in case of a symmetric configuration (Vl = Vr).

So the global filter will give a maximum response for a symmetric maximum (like with a light road on a dark background, vertical, with a width less than 2.tau).

By rearranging the terms, you can see that the filter also yields the smallest of the left and right gradients, V - Vm and V - Vp (clamped to zero).